# Use of express.static middleware

Tags: node.js, express, static

Both below codes serve index.html at localhost:3000/ when the server is started.

Use of `express.static`

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express'); 
const PORT = process.env.port || 3000;
const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, '../public');

var app = express();
app.use(express.static(publicPath));
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
})
```

Use of `app.get`

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const PORT = process.env.port || 3000;
const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, '../public');

var app = express();

app.get('/',(req,res) => {
  res.sendFile(publicPath + '/index.html');
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
})
```

So why someone would choose `express.static` over `app.get` to serve static html file. What's the use of `static` middle ware on express

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that doesn't use `express.static will` fail when serving any other static page that isn't index.html, even if index.html included other static files(as a css) it would fail.

Comment: Why it would fail ? any particular reason ?

Comment: What you are doing with the sendFile line, Express is just serving your /index.html when the client request for the direction '/', if for example the client requested '/home.html.'  ExpressJS(actually Node.JS) woudln't know where to find it, because you never told it where it is. With `app.use(express.static(publicPath))` you are telling Express that it should find any static file requested by the client in publicPath. If your /index.html/ included a css, it also should be served and you never told Express where to find it(You do it with the express.static line).